# How can I add an event listener to a select element?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add an event listener to a select element and execute an action when an option is selected.  My HTML code is:

```
<select id="a_background" name="background" class="widget">
 <option value="1">Yes</option>
 <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
</select>
```

So when `Yes` is selected: do something, If `No` is selected: do something else

Here is what I have so far:

```
var activities = document.getElementById("a_background");
var options = activities.querySelectorAll("option");

activities.addEventListener("changed", function() {

  if (options == "addNew")
  {
    alert('add New selected');
  }

 else 
  { 
    alert('add None selected');
  }
});
```

Due to restrictions I cannot call a function within the select element. For example `<select onChange="myFunction()" id="a_background">`  That is why I would like to add an event listener.

Comment: Have you done any research into "javascript event handlers" or jquery event handlers? What specifically have you tried and what issues are you running into?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @scrappedcola I've done research on both. I would like to use pure JavaScript since I'm not able to add a Jquery library

Comment: @scrappedcola I updated my question to include a code example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That could be simply done using the `addEventListener()` function :

```js
document.querySelector('#a_background').addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (this.value == "1") {
    console.log('Yes selected');
  }else{
     console.log('No selected');
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="a_background" name="background" class="widget">
 <option value="1">Yes</option>
 <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `.change()` function for this. Inside this function you can compare your value and do your operations accordingly.

[Read Here](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#a_background").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
      console.log("Yes");
    } else {
      console.log("No");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="a_background" name="background" class="widget">
 <option value="1">Yes</option>
 <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Be carefull, no jquery tag in the OP

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki yes Just gave him an alternative

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Although this is a great solution Unfortunately I am only able to use a pure JavaScript

Comment: Check my answer @Mariton

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I updated my question to include a code example.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("a_background").addEventListener("change", function(){
     var e = document.getElementById("a_background");
     var selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
     if(selected =='yes')
        doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `onchange="myFunction()"` instead of `onChange="myFunction()"`

```js
function myFunction()
{
  console.log(document.getElementById("a_background").value == 1 ? 'Yes selected' : 'No selected');
}
```

```html
<select id="a_background" name="background" class="widget" onchange="myFunction()">
 <option value="1">Yes</option>
 <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. OP specifically stated that they could not use an inline event.

Comment: As stated I cannot use an inline event